Problem when flipping a 2D sprite in Unity
I have a 2D character that can move left and right and jump. the character's original sprite is from left to right (head in the right direction). when the character moves backwards, it turns the sprite to the left, but when this happens, the Box collider (green box) responsible for collisions becomes misaligned from the character. I need that when the sprite is flipped, it stays in the same place without leaving the Box collider. How to fix this? note: I am using the SpriteRenderer.flipX property to flip the sprite.
Normal sprite
Flipped sprite
(note that the green box, the collider, is a little bit misaligned from the sprite)
I already tried multiplying transform.localScale.x by -1, but that created another problem.

Move the pivot to the center of the rectangular portion of the body.  The pivot is likely centered to the entire sprite which is not the center of the rectangular portion of the body.  Compare where the center of the box collider is to the pivot of the sprite.

To fix the issue, you need to adjust the Pivot point of your sprite. The Pivot point is the point around which the sprite rotates or flips.
Here's how to do it:

Select your sprite in the Hierarchy panel.
In the Inspector window, find the Sprite Renderer component.
Click on the Sprite Editor button next to the Sprite field.
In the Sprite Editor window, you'll see a white circle representing the Pivot point.
Drag the Pivot point to the center of your sprite (or the point where you want the sprite to flip around).
Click Apply to save the changes.

Now, when you flip the sprite using SpriteRenderer.flipX, the sprite should flip around the Pivot point, and the Box Collider should stay aligned with the sprite.
Alternatively, you can also adjust the Pivot point programmatically by setting the SpriteRenderer.pivot property. However, using the Sprite Editor is a more visual and intuitive approach.
As for multiplying transform.localScale.x by -1, it's not the recommended approach in this case, as it can cause other issues with your sprite's rotation and positioning.

it worked. Actually, my sprite is an animation, so i need to move the pivot for all the frames. Is there an easier way to edit the pivot for all the images?

To me, it looks like the visible content of the source image is not centered correctly inside the transparent area, so I would suggest checking that first.
I reproduced the issue in Godot to give a better understanding of what I'm talking about.

The sprite is visually aligned to the center of a collider:



Yet suddenly moves if I flip it horizontally:



Now look at the actual image boundaries - the cat is clearly shifted to the right:


You either have to modify the image itself or try adjusting the pivot, as @hijinxbassist already mentioned in the comment section. The second option didn't work for me.
